# Modify several field variables at once in Java 8

Tags: java

I am creating a map application that has a class with all the colours used to paint the map. The colours are just static field variables. I need to implement a colourblind mode and I was thinking a neat (and time efficient) solution would be to take all my colour variables in the class and modify them.

Is there any way to process many field variables at once in Java 8, or do I need to add them to a list and run through them like that?

Comment: It would be good, if you could give us with some base scenrio (code) to which we can reference and give suggestions.

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables should be used to describe attributes of the class (e.g. an instance counter). Using them to contain attributes of an instance, though possible, is a design error that will bring you many troubles as your app evolves.

If you need only one instance of the Map, define it as a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). On any case, I suggest you to not using static variables for things that describe a particular instance (like the colors of a particular map).

Concerning how to assign many fields with one statement, take a look at BeanUtils#copyProperties here:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-

Comment: It might be a good idea to enhance your answer to tell the OP why it is a bad idea and how your suggestion solves her problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using reflections but be aware of all the possible exceptions:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Colors {
    public static int COLOR1 = 123;
    public static int COLOR2 = 321;
}

public class Test3 {
    public static void modify(Class<?> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
                f.setInt(f, 666);
            } 
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before: " + Colors.COLOR1);
        System.out.println("Before: " + Colors.COLOR2);

        modify(Colors.class);

        System.out.println("After: " + Colors.COLOR1);
        System.out.println("After: " + Colors.COLOR2);
    }
}
```

But I don't think this is a clean solution. This hides dependencies and isn't really OOP-like. You should use an interface which defines getters for each color. Then you can implement two classes from this interface. One class for normal colors the other class for colorblind colors. 
When loading your application settings you create an instance of one of those classes depending of the user settings.